CMS from a practitioner perspective
I understand what CMS are but I am curious why it is an interesting products for traders.
What type of views can be expressed using CMS and not using vanilla products?
Also I would be curious what type of structure are mostly traded with CMS . I heard that CMS spread options are for example commonly traded and I am wondering why. I would be interested in examples.
Thank you!

https://mfe.baruch.cuny.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/IRC_Lecture6_2019.pdf slides 13ff "[Constant Maturity S]waps are used by corporates or investors seeking to maintain a constant asset or liability duration of their portfolios. They also provide a natural vehicle for market participants who wish to take a view on the shape of the swap curve."

@DimitriVulis Ok I see thank you. But why for example buying a 5s10s CMS steepener instead of a 5s10s IRS swap steepener? In the second case you have the roll down which you don't have in the CMS spread, but interested in general by the PnL difference between these two positions. Thank you :)
